# Sorry, we have no imagery here... - Google indexed pages | WMT content keyword | Googlebot

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-search, google-search-console, googlebot, google-index

We just suddenly noticed that there are "imagery" and "sorry" on our Google WMT top content keywords. Also, when searching Google using "site:domain +imagery" this "Sorry, we have no imagery here..." is on its description.

I have searched and the only way to avoid this is to replace the Google Maps with a static one. Are there any other ways to fix this?

Is this a Google Maps bug? Or am I just missing something?

By the way, I am just plotting company markers on my Google Map (10 per page).

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to not initialize the Google Map when a Google Bot visits your page, as mentioned in [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/53547/9877) on Webmasters.

```
var isGoogleBot = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('googlebot') > -1;
if (isGoogleBot)
    return; // "Sorry, we have no imagery here" BUG
else
    // Setup the map
```

Comment: Yes this is one possible solution however I think Google does not allow this? I just read from other posts.